# C# ListView Data Writing Speed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I am creating an UI for my bootloader software. I have used ListView object to view flash memory data in MCU. Data size is about 150kB. Writing data to ListView is not fast as I want. It takes around 4-4.5 second. I tried some ways that it is faster but these ways hasnot worked. But I want it to be faster. How can I do that?

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Read speed of flash is only going to be as fast as the memory and will depend if flash is fragmented.  You could try to defrag the flash and see if time improves.

Comment: @jdweng my problem isn't MCU flash read process. Main problem is listview in C#.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could provide some code. It will be better to optimize your existing code.